# Task scheduling algorithm in dart

Tags: javascript, arrays, dart

Creating an application that helps assign user tasks. They all start at the same time and the tasks take the same amount of time to complete. I want to create a round robin algorithm to assign tasks to the users. How do I implement this in JS and or in Dart

ie.

```
var users = ["a","b","c"]
var tasks = 10
```

The users will have the following tasks

```
"a" => "1","4","7","10"
"b" => "2","5","8"
"c" => "3","6","9"
```

How do I implement a function that will compute which user does which task number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a trivial use of modulo:

```dart
// Calls [createTask] with the numbers 1 through [taskCount].
// Assigns the created tasks to the names in a round-robin manner.
// Returns a map from names to lists of tasks.
Map<N, List<T>> roundRobin<N, T>(List<N> names, int taskCount, T createTask(int number)) {
  var tasks = [for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) <T>[]];
  for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < taskCount; i++) {
    tasks[i % tasks.length].add(createTask(i + 1));
  }
  return {for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) names[i]: tasks[i]};
}
```

Comment: @Irn Quick question.  How would I write the method if I just want to know if `task 1` belongs to `a`  and `task 2` belongs to `b`

Comment: @Irn Tried your code https://dartpad.dev/8815170357279882e70d3657d468f255?null_safety=true and it fails

Comment: The function that @lrn wrote in his answer takes three arguments.  You called it with only two.

Comment: To just answer the question "does task number *n* belong to name number *m*", you just need to check whether `((n - 1) % names.length) == m`. (The `- 1` is just because I counted tasks from 1 and names from 0).